# Looking for Working Weather Dashboard Widget

Tags: dashboard-widget, dashboard, macos

So the weather widget apple includes with macOS no longer works. It's been broken for a while now, I suspect it's never coming back. Especially since it was powered by Yahoo. Also Apple's "dashboard widget" directory hasn't been updated in 10+ years. So that's useless.

I'm looking for a simple little widget that will give me current conditions and a 7+ day forecast. Nothing complicated. But it is really useful and it's a bummer not having it.

Answer (score 4):

I modified Apple's Dashboard widget to use an entirely different weather API. You can download it from https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/i-fixed-apples-broken-weather-dashboard-widget.2225715/.

You'll need to grab API keys from DarkSky and MapQuest and add them to the top of `weatherParser.js` inside the modified widget. This process is extensively documented in Widget's readme.

---

Alternately, you can also use the [FairWeather widget](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/information/fairweather.html).  It's not quite as pretty as Apple's widget, but it gets its weather data directly from the NOAA's servers, so I suspect it's less likely to break than something which pulls from a private company.

Sadly, the original download link is broken, so I uploaded it here: https://macintoshgarden.org/apps/fair-weather

Comment: FairWeather also available through archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20160809080707/http://ch4productions.com/pub/widgets/fairweather.zip

I confirm that it works fine on 10.14.6.

Comment: @iled I just tried it out in 10.14.6 but it's not working. I typed in my zip code but i can't get it to check MY weather, it only checks Cupertino weather. Is there a trick to it?

Comment: @l008com The Tiger-modified widget broke literally a couple weeks after I posted. :( Use Fair Weather!

Comment: And now you can use the original widget again, because I fixed it! @l008com

Answer (score -1):

[image]

the weather widget seems not to work on my 10.13.6... lands in a infinite Validating loop...

Comment: As IconDaemon said this isn’t the place for this. But, given your screenshot, my first question would be if you added api keys as the instructions indicated.

Comment: yes of course... just according the instruction...

Comment: If it does this for any location you enter, something is wrong with your MapQuest API key. If you post in that that MacRumors forum thread I can help you further, or you could theoretically ask a new question here.